# Unit Testing Entity Framework Core DBContext using a Production Model (Context.Database.EnsureCreated) that contains views

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, .net-core

I have a series of tests that are currently using the recommended practice for testing query logic here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-with-the-database.  This has been working wonderfully but I've encountered a snag.  We have an existing database used by other products that has a view, this view handles a lot of boiler plate and I leave it in another teams hands to ensure it works correctly.  But One of my pieces of logic depends on it so I wanted to mock that view up similar to how I would any existing table, with some known "good" data to complete out my query testing.

Were I using an InMemory context Microsoft's suggestion would be to do something similar to:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ViewItem>(entity =>
    {
        if (!Database.IsInMemory())
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();
            entity.ToView("vTestView");
        }
        else
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Name);
        }
    });
}
```

However as I am not using an InMemory database does anyone have any suggestion about best practices for mocking a DBContext view for testing purposes.
Example Fixture

```
public TestDatabaseFixture()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_databaseInitialized)
            {
                using (var context = CreateContext())
                {
                    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    //populate database
                    PopulateTableOne(context);
                    PopulateTableTwo(context);
                    //Want to populate view with dummy data
                    PopulateViewOne(context)

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                _databaseInitialized = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public MyContext CreateContext()
        => new MyContext(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(GetConnectionString())
                .Options);
```

Some other info:
Unit Testing Database is SQL Server Developer

So far my only idea is to explicitly check the connection string for a value during OnModelCreating to do something similar to the IsInMemory check (not tried if that actually works)

Comment: Why not use the InMemory option? it is easy enough to implement and "closer" to the code than supporting unit tests using an actual db